# After upgrading to .net6 from .net4.8 FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration does not exists

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I just upgraded my .net4.8 web app to .net6 using upgrade assistant among the other errors I get, in my SignIn function I cannot use the following:

```
WsFederationConfiguration config = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration;
```

I get the error:

> 'FederatedAuthentication' does not contain a definition for 'FederationConfiguration'

It seems like FederationConfiguration is no longer supported in .net6. What is the best alternative?

Comment: First port of call would be the AspNetCore nuget packages, does
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.WsFederation have the utilities you need?
There is also information at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: .NET 6 is .NET **Core** 6. A lot of classes and APIs were never migrated to .NET Core because they were no longer popular, like WebForms and several parts of WCF. What are you trying to do? `WsFederationConfiguration` is used for SOAP services, not for user login. You can still add SOAP references with [the proper Visual Studio extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide)

Comment: If you want to authenticate with Azure AD or ADFS check [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/ws-federation?view=aspnetcore-6.0). For Azure AD though, there's support even in the new project template. You can [add Microsoft Identity authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) in a few steps too.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos other than authentication, the web app itself creates, updates or disable users in AAD. I will check the extension you provided. Thank you for your input.